# Grails access map variable in GSP with extra brackets around the values

Tags: grails, groovy

I create a Map in my Service, which is called from my Controller.  This map I pass into a GSP.  I need to store the id into a hidden var. But the id comes in as myId =

```
[[20]]
```

and to generate unique names and id's i need to concatenate this with another string. Thus, I need just the number, 20. Below is what the service returns into groupRef

```
[[{myId=20, groups=[{groupId=33, gNames=[{name=Prime, show=true}]}]}]]

<g:set var="myId" value="${groupRef.myId}" />
```

which yields [[20]].

How do I get to just the number?

Comment: That looks to me like the `toString` representation of a list of lists of maps, so your `myId` variable would end up as a list of lists of number (or string - the `toString` representation doesn't distinguish between the Integer `20`, the Long `20L` and the String `"20"`)

Comment: If that is indeed the case then you could try something like `groupRef.myId.flatten().first()`, but more productive might be to look at the service code and work out why it's wrapping the result in two layers of lists to start with...

Comment: Well, why do you have a list of list in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, you have a list, inside a list, inside a list - as many levels as there are [] bracket pairs. Try this:

```
<g:set var="myIdInside" value="myId[0][0]" />
```

And, check your Service, to see if you can modify what it's returning, to negate having to do what I just showed you above.